# Matplotlib + Ubuntu + GTK3 no plot shown

Tags: ubuntu, matplotlib, gtk3

I can see the GUI but not the plot. No errors, even the mouse coordinates are okay, but no plot using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

Then

```
$ python -c 'import matplotlib; import matplotlib.pyplot; print(matplotlib.backends.backend)'
GTK3Agg
```

I installed the following on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gi
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-devel
sudo pip install matplotlib
sudo pip install numpy
```

What could be the problem? Or how can I further debug this?

Answer (score 0):

This is working on Ubuntu 14.04. All packages from apt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```